# How to sum total amount without grouping even have duplicated number?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

```
table_a                    table_b
                    
desc    amount  ID        vcref     ID
banana   2.00   101       VC10001   101
apple    3.00   101       VC10001   101
orange   5.00   101       VC10003   101

select sum(a.amount),b.vcref from table_a a,table_b b where a.ID=b.ID group by b.vcref;

result 
   20.0     VC10001 
   10.0     VC10003
-------------------------------------------
```

May I know it is possible to show result like this ?

```
result 
   10.0    VC10001
   10.0    VC10001
   10.0    VC10003
```

Anyone help is much appreciated.

Comment: How do you get `20` and `10` from `2`, `3` and `5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a correlated subquery:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  table_a (c_desc, amount, id) as
  3    (select 'banana', 2, 101 from dual union all
  4     select 'apple' , 3, 101 from dual union all
  5     select 'orange', 5, 101 from dual
  6    ),
  7  table_b (vcref, id) as
  8    (select 'vc1001', 101 from dual union all
  9     select 'vc1001', 101 from dual union all
 10     select 'vc1003', 101 from dual
 11    )
```

Query:

```
 12  select b.vcref,
 13    (select sum(a.amount) from table_a a where a.id = b.id) total
 14  from table_b b;

VCREF       TOTAL
------ ----------
vc1001         10
vc1001         10
vc1003         10

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select the sum as an inner query:

```sql
select
  (select sum(amount) from table_a) as result,
  vcref
from table_b
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, just edit my early post ID is same number.

Comment: That results in **9 rows** (which is not what Daniel wants).

Comment: @little you're right. Join deleted!